# Where can i capture the ACTION_CANCEL in child when parent's onInterceptTouchEvent() return true？

Tags: java, android

This is the part of the annotation of `onInterceptTouchEvent()`:

> If you return true from here, you will not receive any
>    following events: the target view will receive the same event but
>   with the action {@link MotionEvent#ACTION_CANCEL}, and all further
>    events will be delivered to your onTouchEvent() method and no longer
>   appear here.

It said that if you return true in parent's `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method, your child will receive `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` event. Where can I put a `log.d` to capture `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` in order to prove that child have received the  `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture it in the child's `onTouchEvent()`. If that child view is not a custom view, you can set an [`OnTouchListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) on the child and capture it in the `onTouch()` callback.

Comment: I add a ImageView with `OnTouchListener` which is return true,but i can't capture ACTION_CANCEL in it. I have read the source code of `ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent()` and i did't found the place where deliver the `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` to the child(I can find the place that deliver event to parent's `onTouchEvent()`).This question have bother me for three days!

Comment: Looking at the source (for API 22), `ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent()` calls `dispatchTransformedTouchEvent()`, which calls `dispatchTouchEvent()` on the child views. View.dispatchTouchEvent() calls to the `OnTouchListener` or the View's `onTouchEvent()`.